# Unequal circles within circle with least possible radius?

Tags: geometry, inequality, circles, packing-problem

It is the classical will-my-cables-fit-within-the-tube-problem which lead me to the interest of [circle packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing).  So basically, I have 3 circles where r = 3 and 1 circle where r = 7 and I am trying to find the least r for an outer circles of these 4 smaller circles.

After a couple of hours of thinking and some sketches with a compass I am getting close to the actual result.
But how can I calculate this?
With what formula?

**EDIT:**
Thanks for the great answer.
And then I come to wonder.
What happens if you add another of the small circles, so you have four circles with r = 3?  It is very close to 11.7

Comment: I finished the second arrangement. It is indeed slightly better. Placed second answer, with expression for $R$ as the largest root of a cubic.

Comment: With five circles, draw the analogous diagram to my second answer.. you still get an angle $\beta$ with $\sin \beta = B / (R-B).$ Instead of $2 \beta,$ the centers to be considered are at $3 \beta$ and $\beta.$ I used a computer algebra system (gp-Pari) to simplify the final expression, making a polynomial equation involving $R,A,B.$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clearly radius 10 is not quite enough; once you have an arrangement like this, it may be possible to find the eaxct outer radius, but in any case it can be estimated fairly well. Reminds me of these, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sangaku

I drew in some trial outer circles, $r = 11$ worked with room to spare, so I split the difference, $r=10.5 = 21/2$ also worked with just a little extra room.

EDIT: did it in coordinates, I thought it was going to be a degree four polynomial but there was cancellation and it became linear, the best outer radius is
$$\frac{637}{61} \approx 10.4426     $$

EEDDIITT: did it over with symbols. If the larger given radius, now 7, is called $A,$ and the smaller given radius, now 3, is called $B,$ then the radius of the circumscribed circle is  $$  R = \frac{A^2 (A+2B)}{A^2 + AB - B^2}.  $$

[image]

Comment: http://www.wasan.jp/english/index.html

Comment: @Alan, this book is affordable and well reviewed: http://press.princeton.edu/titles/8646.html  The earlier book with Pedoe is out of reach

Comment: That's a shame about the book by Fukagawa and Pedoe, I wish I could find a copy in a library somewhere. Perhaps the best problems are in the book by Fukagawa and Rothman. Still, there are hundreds of problems on the tablets!

Comment: It appears we can do very slightly better by pulling the middle 3 circle and the 7 circle apart by just a hair. I realized this because the best arrangement for four equal radii has the centers at the corners of a square. I will leave this here, it is done correctly, it is just not (well, probably not) the absolute best possible. Sigh.

Comment: @Alan, if you have a thousand dollars to spare, http://www.amazon.com/Japanese-Temple-Geometry-Problems-Sangaku/dp/0919611214  I can borrow some quirky stuff through interlibrary loan, but I don't think I would want to risk it in this case. I've never lost or damaged an interlibrary loan book before, but... I imagine there are copies in some Canadian universities in the province where Pedoe worked.

Comment: @WillJagy My mind kept spinning about this just before I got to sleep last night, and I also realized that the middle 3 circle have to be apart.  After work today I think I will create a set of trigonometry functions for calculating the radii given that you set the angle between center of the 3 circles.  And then bruteforce the whole shabang.

Answer (score 5):

I finished up the other approach.  The arrangement with larger radius $A$ and three circles of smaller radius $B,$ all tangent to an outer circle of radius $R,$ gives a cubic $$  R^3 - (A+2B) R^2 + A B R + A B^2 = 0. $$ For $A=7, B=3$ this gives $R \approx 10.397547282.$  Note that the coefficient of $R^3$ is positive, when $R=0$ the result is positive, but when $R=A$ the result is negative (for $A>B>0$). So there is a negative root, an unsuitable root $0 < R < A,$ and finally the real thing when $R>A.$ Notice that, for $A=B=1,$ we get the correct $R=1+\sqrt 2,$ meaning the centers of the four small circles are on the corners of a square, and the center of the circumscribing circle is at the center of the same square, all very symmetric in that case.

It is possible for $(A,B,R)$ to come out integers, for example $(A=9,B=5,R=15)$ or $(A=32,B=11,R=44).$ These are in the infinite family $$ A = n^3 + 4 n^2 + 4 n = n (n+2)^2,  B = n^2 + 3 n + 1,  R = n^3 + 5 n^2 + 7 n + 2 = A + B + 1. $$

[image]

The $(9,5,15)$ arrangement is especially good for a diagram here, as there are many visible $30^\circ-60^\circ-90^\circ$ right triangles, as well as one with sides $14,11, 5 \sqrt 3$ where I drew a pale green line in pencil.

[image]

Umm. It turned out it was possible to solve the Diophantine equation for much larger values; it is obvious that $R | A B^2,$ and a little extra fiddling with unique factorization (I'm taking $\gcd(A,B)=1$) shows that $R | AB,$ so that $AB/R$ is an integer, and the equation becomes
$$  R \cdot (A + 2 B - R) = (R + B) \cdot (AB/R).  $$ Here are the first hundred integer solutions

```
               A         B         R      A+2B-R     R+B      AB/R
               9         5        15         4        20         3
              25        22        55        14        77        10
              32        11        44        10        55         8
              75        19        95        18       114        15
             128        93       248        66       341        48
             144        29       174        28       203        24
             147        62       217        54       279        42
             245        41       287        40       328        35
             363       244       671       180       915       132
             384        55       440        54       495        48
             400       183       610       156       793       120
             405       118       531       110       649        90
             507       395      1027       270      1422       195
             567        71       639        70       710        63
             605       237       869       210      1106       165
             784       505      1414       380      1919       280
             800        89       890        88       979        80
             845       404      1313       340      1717       260
             847       190      1045       182      1235       154
             867       847      2057       504      2904       357
            1089       109      1199       108      1308        99
            1183       363      1573       336      1936       273
            1296      1043      2682       700      3725       504
            1440       131      1572       130      1703       120
            1445       906      2567       690      3473       510
            1521       278      1807       270      2085       234
            1536       755      2416       630      3171       480
            1568       435      2030       408      2465       336
            1575       596      2235       532      2831       420
            1805      1253      3401       910      4654       665
            1859       155      2015       154      2170       143
            1936      1845      4510      1116      6355       792
            2023       895      3043       770      3938       595
            2205      1672      4389      1160      6061       840
            2352       181      2534       180      2715       168
            2400      1477      4220      1134      5697       840
            2475       382      2865       374      3247       330
            2527      1266      4009      1050      5275       798
            2560       597      3184       570      3781       480
            2592      1045      3762       920      4807       720
            2601       820      3485       756      4305       612
            2645      2169      5543      1440      7712      1035
            2925       209      3135       208      3344       195
            3179       687      3893       660      4580       561
            3249      1205      4579      1080      5784       855
            3584       239      3824       238      4063       224
            3645      3421      8397      2090     11818      1485
            3703      2248      6463      1736      8711      1288
            3757       502      4267       494      4769       442
            3872      1967      6182      1624      8149      1232
            3971      1076      5111      1012      6187       836
            4205      4188     10121      2460     14309      1740
            4335       271      4607       270      4878       255
            4375      2871      7975      2142     10846      1575
            4693       885      5605       858      6490       741
            4704      3905      9940      2574     13845      1848
            4761      2233      7337      1890      9570      1449
            4851      1555      6531      1430      8086      1155
            5103      3590      9693      2590     13283      1890
            5184       305      5490       304      5795       288
            5408      3249      9386      2520     12635      1872
            5415       638      6061       630      6699       570
            5600       993      6620       966      7613       840
            5625      2888      9025      2376     11913      1800
            5733      1364      7161      1300      8525      1092
            5760      2513      8616      2170     11129      1680
            5808      1745      7678      1620      9423      1320
            5819      2130      8165      1914     10295      1518
            5887      4411     11629      3080     16040      2233
            6137       341      6479       340      6820       323
            6144      5707     14048      3510     19755      2496
            6727      5340     13795      3612     19135      2604
            6875      2807     10025      2464     12832      1925
            6877      1945      8947      1820     10892      1495
            7200       379      7580       378      7959       360
            7200      4939     13470      3608     18409      2640
            7497       790      8295       782      9085       714
            7569      4510     13079      3510     17589      2610
            7623      6383     16203      4186     22586      3003
            7744      1227      8998      1200     10225      1056
            7840      4059     12628      3330     16687      2520
            7935      1684      9683      1620     11367      1380
            8019      3592     12123      3080     15715      2376
            8064      2155     10344      2030     12499      1680
            8112      3115     11570      2772     14685      2184
            8125      2634     10975      2418     13609      1950
            8379       419      8799       418      9218       399
            8649      5489     15469      4158     20958      3069
            8993      1353     10373      1326     11726      1173
            9248      7085     18530      4888     25615      3536
            9251      4491     14471      3762     18962      2871
            9477      3437     13257      3094     16694      2457
            9583      8835     21793      5460     30628      3885
            9680       461     10142       460     10603       440
           10051       958     11017       950     11975       874
           10240      6061     17632      4730     23693      3520
           10571      5510     17081      4510     22591      3410
           10625      2036     12725      1972     14761      1700
           10647     10256     24999      6160     35255      4368
           10816      2605     13546      2480     16151      2080
             A         B         R       A+2B-R     R+B       AB/R
```